# How to map array of objects into second array where I can grab dynamic fields to return without using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a large array of objects of around 1000 items. Based on a condition I need to grab only a few fields from each object in the array and map it to new smaller array. So the fields needed from each object is dynamic and I don't want to use a for loop inside every loop of the map function.

```
function mapData(fieldsNeeded, data) {
  //something like map the data with dynamic fields
  //I want to replace the for loop with something quicker like object destruction or something?
  return data.map((item) => {
    const newItem = {};
    for(const field of fieldsNeeded) {
      newItem[field] = item[field];
    }
    
    return newItem;
  }
}

let fieldsNeeded;
if(something) {
  fieldsNeeded = ['a', 'c'];
} else {
  fieldsNeeded = ['b', 'c'];
}

const data = [ { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6 }, { a: 7, b: 8, c: 9 }, { a: 10, b: 11, c: 12 } ];

const mappedData = mapData(fieldsNeeded, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to simplify your code.

```js
function mapData(fieldsNeeded, data) {
  return data.map(item => Object.fromEntries(fieldsNeeded.map(f => [f, item[f]])));
}
let fieldsNeeded = ['a', 'c'];
const data = [ { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6 }, { a: 7, b: 8, c: 9 }, { a: 10, b: 11, c: 12 } ];
console.log(mapData(fieldsNeeded, data));
```